# Regular Expression Equality

Tags: regular-expressions

I am wondering about this small question, why aren't these regular expressions equal?

$(a+b)^* a^*$ and $(a^* b)^* a^*$

Comment: This is kind of like asking why two different algorithms for calculating factorial aren't equal, even though they produce the same output.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression is defined by a syntax: it means that a regular expression is a sequence of symbols following certain rules.

If two regular expression have different symbols, they are different.

However, it is natural to define a semantic, or interpretation, associated to regular expression. The interpretation is sometimes denoted as $\mathcal{L}(e)$ for a regular expression $e$.

While $(a+b)^*a^* \neq (a^*b)^*a^*$ because the sequences of symbols are differents, their interpretations are equal: $\mathcal{L}((a+b)^*a^*) = \mathcal{L}((a^*b)^*a^*) = \{a,b\}^*$.

It is common when there are no ambiguity to omit the interpretation symbol $\mathcal{L}$ and to consider a regular expression as a language, but it is an abuse of notation.

Comment: Thanks! i agree with you! , as regular expressions are mere notation having sequence of symbols, but whenever if ask to compare regular expression, ideally how i should compare it, base on semantic or base on interpretation? and then how this is equal ? (a+b)* a * == (a* b*)*a* ?, they are not semantically same right?

Comment: Using syntax or semantic depends on the context, there is no general answer. $(a+b)^*a^*$ and $(a^*b^*)^*a^*$ are semantically the same, they both correspond to the language of all words over the alphabet $\{a, b\}$.

Comment: Just wanted to make it complete here is formal proof for the same,    R=(a*b)* a*
`proof`
R=R1 a*
R1= [b,ab,aab,aaab,aaaab,.....]

R1= ε + (a+b)*b; --->1

Now,
R1=(a*b)* = ε + (a*b)(a*b)*
R1= ε + [a*.(a*b)*]b ----> 2

(a+b)* = [a*.(a*b)*]

now by shifting rule,

[a*.(a*b)*] = [(a*.b)*.a*];

Hence, (a+b)* = [(a*.b)*.a*];

Comment: Is there a way to compare two given regexps that may have different sequences of symbols to determine if their interpretations are identical?  Some sort of "canonicalizing" transformation that can be applied to both sides after which identical interpretations implies identical canonicalized sequences?

Comment: @davidbak the only general way I know of is converting both expressions into NFA, converting those NFA into DFA, and minimizing those DFA and checking if they are the same. Though the NFA-to-DFA part is cost-heavy.